# Vertex tool is converting multi linestring into multi curve

Tags: qgis

After editing a PostGIS MutliLineString layer in QGIS with the vertex tool I can not commit the table edits because the MultiLineStrings have been converted to MultiCurves. The error message is:

> Could not commit changes to layer road_cl_segmented
>
> Errors: ERROR: 1 geometries not changed.
> Provider errors:
> PostGIS error while changing geometry values: ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiCurve) does not match column type (MultiLineString)

QGIS 3.16.3, PostGIS 3.1

I can not change the PostGIS geometry type. How can I prevent the vertex tool from changing the geometry type?

Answer (score 2):

When the QGIS project was created the PostGIS geometry type was "Geometry". Later the PostGIS geometry type was converted to "MultiLineString". QGIS viewed the Geometry as MultiCurve and saved that in the project. By adding the layer/table to the QGIS project after the geometry type was changed to MultiLineString fixed my problem. Sorry for the noise.